# How to set a value of textfield as a session attribute in jsp before rendering?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ajax, jsp

suppose I have code

```
<html>
<head>
    <script>
        function ses()
        {
        var r=document.getElementById("rollno").value;
        session.setAttribute("rollno",r);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="process.jsp">
        RollNO: <input type="text" name="rollno" id="rollno" onblur=ses()>
        Admission no<input type="text" name="anum" id="anum">
        <input  type="submit" value="Next"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

I want to set session attribute as rollno is entered in textfield but before submitting the form .
There is any alternate for the code for storing session without submitting form.

Comment: What session attribute?

Comment: Use the attribute onSubmit in the form tag. Declare a function and return true.

Comment: i want to execute session.setAttriute("rollno",rollno) butbefore submitting form

Comment: Session is a server side thing, it does not exists in the browser, so you can't do what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simplest way to set servlet without submitting/rendring form without using servlet.

Code for TextField

```
RollNO:<input type="text" name="rollno" id="rollno" onblur="ses(this.value)">
```

Javascript for file containing the textfield:

```
function ses(roll)
{   
    var req=getRequestObject();
    req.onreadystatechange=function(){handleResponse(req);};
    req.open("GET","set_session.jsp?rollno="+roll,true);
    req.send(null);   
}


function handleResponse(req)
{ 
    if(req.readyState==4)
        {
            alert("Session has been set");
        }
}


function getRequestObject()
{
if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
{
return(new XMLHttpRequest());
}
else if(window.ActiveXObject)
{
return(new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP"));
}
else
{
return(null);
}
}
```

File set_session.jsp:

```
<%
  String rollno=request.getParameter("rollno");
  session.setAttribute("roll",rollno);
%>
```

Answer (score 1):

You simply cannot do what you want to achieve. After the rendering (HTML generation) of the JSP page, you are on the client side. The user session simply does not exist in the web browser (HTTP is a *stateless* protocol).

The usual approach if you want something in the sessions is to use a Servlet. You *POST* your form to this servlet, you get the `HttpSession` from the `HttpRequest` parameter of the `doPost` method, then you put your variable from the request parameters into the session. After this, you redirect the client to make a *GET* request to the target JSP page.

Of course you can do all this without actually submitting the form, using AJAX. For example with the jQuery `$.ajax` function:

```
var params = {
    rollno: document.getElementById("rollno").value
};
$.ajax({
    url: 'myServlet?' + $.param(params),
    type: 'post'
});
```

Then you can handle it with the Servlet:

```
@WebServlet(name="myServlet", urlPatterns={"/myServlet"})
public class MyServlet extends HttpServlet {
    @Override
    public void doPost(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse resp) {
        HttpSesssion session = req.getSession();
        // put the request parameter into the session
        session.setAttribute("rollno", req.getParameter("rollno"));
        // if this wouldn't be AJAX, we would redirect the user
        // resp.sendRedirect("myOtherPage.jsp");
    } 
}
```

Comment: You can just simply make a post request to the servlet using AJAX. I am adding an example.

Comment: or can i use localStorage.setItem() for storing if yes then how to use the variable to store in jsp variable 
var r=localStorage.getItem("roll") ; //
String rollno=(String)r;   //error stating cannot convert void to string

Comment: JSP cannot access the localStorage. JSP is on the server, localStorage is on the client.